# How can i get audio from a YouTube video and put into my Visual Basic Form based Music Player?

Tags: forms, android-studio, audio-player

i created a Form with a custom layout and i wish to add in it a Music Player that picks a song from YouTube URL. Then, for example, the user could create a playlist with a lot of music URLs and play them!
Thanks!

Comment: Please, show us some code you have tried so far.

Comment: Unofrtunately i don't have a code, i only did the graphical part.